# Make uniqBy with es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```js
const uniqBy = (arr, fn) => {
  let res = []
  const hash = new Set()
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    const foo = typeof fn === 'function' ? fn(arr[i]) : arr[i][fn]
    if (!hash.has(foo)) {
      res.push(arr[i])
      hash.add(foo)
    }
  }
  return res
}

console.log(uniqBy([2.1, 1.2, 2.3], Math.floor)) // [2.1, 1.2]
console.log(uniqBy([{
  x: 1
}, {
  x: 2
}, {
  x: 1
}], 'x')) // [{x: 1 },{ x: 2 }]
```

That's my code to achieve uniqBy, but the code is too much, I want to get a better way with less code

Comment: The  is what the best answerer gets or what?

Comment: You can't write that shorter.

Comment: @Dan D. you can write everything shorter. If thats better is another thing

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is better suited for  https://codereview.stackexchange.com - the code works, the question is how to improve it.

Comment: @ Oleg Estekhin Thank you for your suggest

Answer (score 2):

```
 const uniqBy = (arr, fn, set = new Set) => arr.filter(el => (v => !set.has(v) && set.add(v))(typeof fn === "function" ? fn(el) : el[fn]));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it's not a correct solution, it failed by test case

Comment: @Vic oh right, i messed up the property access part. Now it works http://jsbin.com/kejisohewa/edit?console

Comment: @ Jonas W. Awesome! That's so impressive, I like your solution

Answer (score 1):

[`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) is a decent alternative to [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) when comparing the uniqueness of `variables` using `keys`.

```js
// UniqBy.
const uniqBy = (arr, fn) => [...new Map(arr.reverse().map((x) => [typeof fn === 'function' ? fn(x) : x[fn], x])).values()]

// Proof.
console.log(uniqBy([2.1, 1.2, 2.3], Math.floor)) // [2.1, 1.2]
console.log(uniqBy([{x: 1}, {x: 2}, {x: 1}], 'x')) // [{x: 1},{x: 2}]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my take at it

```js
const uniqBy = (arr, fn, obj={}) => ((arr.reverse().forEach(item => obj[typeof fn === 'function' ? fn(item) : item[fn]] = item)), Object.values(obj))

console.log(uniqBy([2.1, 2.3, 3.2], Math.floor))
console.log(uniqBy([{x:1}, {x:2}, {x:1}, {x:4}], 'x'))
```

Comment: @Vic I have made the change.